# Pear - spreadsheet_excel_writer insertBitmap function error

Tags: php, pear, spreadsheet-excel-writer

I am stuck into the problem in SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_WRITER. When i am using insertBitmap() function it is generating an error and not embeding the bitmap image in excel.

I have gone through the link ([PEAR Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer insertBitmap() not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796992/pear-spreadsheet-excel-writer-insertbitmap-not-working-correctly)
) but it didn't helped me out....

My code is below...

```
    $exp_name = "National_Regional_Scores_" . time() . ".xls";
    $file_location = $exp_name;
    $workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
    $workbook->setVersion(8);
    $worksheetName = "National_Regional_Scores";

    $worksheet = &$workbook->addWorksheet($worksheetName);
    $worksheet->setColumn(0, 0, 60);
    $worksheet->setColumn(1, 20 * 2, 10);
    reset($header_file);
    $round = &$workbook->addFormat();
    $round->setNumFormat('0');


    $i = 0;
    foreach ($header_file as $a) {
        $j = 0;

        foreach ($a as $p) {

            if ($i == 1) {
                $format_center = & $workbook->addFormat();
                $format_center->setAlign('center');
                $q = 1;
                $r = 2;
                for ($x = 0; $x < $regions_cnt + 1; $x++) {
                    $worksheet->setMerge(1, $q, 1, $r);
                    $q += 2;
                    $r += 2;
                }


                $worksheet->write($i, $j, $p, $format_center);
                $worksheet->setMerge(1, 1, 1, 2);
            }if ($i == 2) {
                $format_center = & $workbook->addFormat();
                $format_center->setAlign('center');
                $worksheet->write($i, $j, $p, $format_center);
            } else {
                $format_center = & $workbook->addFormat();
                if ($j == 0) {
                    $format_center->setTextWrap();
                } else {
                    $format_center->setAlign('center');
                }

                $worksheet->write($i, $j, $p, $format_center);
            }

            $j++;
        }

        $i++;
    }

    $worksheet->insertBitmap('0','0', DOCUMENT_ROOT.'\public\testbmp.bmp','1','1','2','2');
    $worksheet->setRow(0,50);

    $workbook->send($file_location);
    $workbook->close();
    die;
```

The error i am getting is below...

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer_Worksheet::isError() in E:\apd360\staging\mbaup360stage\library\Lib\excel\Worksheet.php on line 3098
```

Please help....

Comment: please add the full code that leads to this error. The code you show does not produce the error.

Comment: I have added the full code....please check and revert...

Comment: where did you get `Lib\excel\Worksheet.php` from?

Comment: i downloaded this from Pear library...

Comment: Then you installed it manually, which seldom works if you don't know what you're doing. Please install it with the PEAR installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yupieeeeeee....

Finally i achieved this....

I just added the **PEAR.PHP** and **PEAR5.PHP** to the excel library and it is working for me...

Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: Thanks I just had the same problem.You saved my  hours.